# Is it possible to enforce the declaration of local variables?

Tags: variables, declaration, livecode

I have defined a local variable

```
 local tSuppressLines
```

I would like to make sure that local variables are checked so that if I have a typo like

```
   if  not tSuppessLines  then
      -- do something
   end if
```

I get a warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, switch on "strict compilation mode" under "script editor" in preferences.

Answer (score 2):

When in the script editor, there is also an item under the "Edit" menu, "Variable Checking", which toggles the same setting, but doesn't make the change persistent - on next launching the IDE, the value set in preferences will be restored.

This can be useful because sometimes you need to edit a script in which variables haven't been consistently declared (and literals haven't been quoted); and don't have time to make and test those changes.  So you can temporarily toggle this checking off; and even if you forget to set it back, the corruption won't spread too far.

(This is an improvement on previous behaviour - before version 6, the menu item toggled the preference item, and vice versa)